# Class Cast Exception retrieving Chosen date from childfragment to show in parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have a `parentfragment` called `Planning` in which I want to show a `DialogFragment` called `DatePickerfragment`.The `DatePickerFragment` has a `button` that when clicked, will show a `datepicker` for the user. The user selects a date and that date should be passed to the `Parent Fragment` in a textview called 'date'.

Unfortunately, everytime I click the `button` the app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.meat_timealpha10.Activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener
    at com.example.android.meat_timealpha10.Fragments.DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(DatePickerFragment.java:29)
```

I know where the error is but I don't know how to fix it.
It refers to this line in the `DatePickerDialogFragment`:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day );
```

The thing is I followed a youtube video and the guy doesn't seem to have any issues. Then again, he doesn't use `nested fragments` like me.
Does anyone know how to fix that error so that the chosen date gets displayed in the `textview`?

Here is my code:

`XML` of `parent fragment` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Fragments.planning">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chooseDate"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:hint="touch here to select date"

        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Following is `Child Fragment DatePickerFragment`:

```
package com.example.android.meat_timealpha10.Fragments;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.meat_timealpha10.R;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public String dateHolder;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day );
    }   

}
```

Code of `parent fragment` ( without imports )

```
public class planning extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public planning() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment planning.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static planning newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        planning fragment = new planning();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }



    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planning,
                container, false);
        final Button chooseDate = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDate);




        chooseDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {

                                        DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                                        datePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "date picker");

                                      }
                                      });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());
        TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(currentDateString);

    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I am fairly new at this so please try to make it easy enough to understand when answering my question.
Thanks in advance people!

Comment: (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity() this is serious problem here  if you want date selected listener in planning Fragment then you got to pass object of palling fragment instead of getActivity

Comment: try with getParentFragment() instead of getctivity

Comment: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getParentFragment()

Comment: else you need to creaet a newInstance function like you did in planning fragment and pass the dateListsnerObject there.. or you can follow the answer given below

Comment: Thank you Adeel, getParentFragment actually fixed this!!

Comment: glad to hear that.. You can upvote my comment if it helped you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it suggested, you can not cast activity to be a Listener, the error occurs in this line: (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity().

you need to implement **DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener** in your fragment and override **onDateSet** function:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}  

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    ...        
}}
```